# can only perform rotation of image view without holding it

Tags: android, image

Hi guys i uses the code below to perform rotation but it only rotates one time and goes back to its original position, how to let the image stay at the rotated position?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="90"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:duration="1000"
android:startOffset="0"
/>
```

xml file of my code

```
 Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
    a.startAnimation(rotation);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
anim.setFillAfter(true);
```

> If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed
>   will persist when it is finished. Defaults to false if not set. Note
>   that this applies to individual animations and when using an
>   AnimationSet to chain animations.